# Why are there 2 version of Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I just notice that at Github, there are 2 version of Laravel. One is this: https://github.com/laravel/laravel and the other is https://github.com/laravel/framework. One has more frequent update than the other. For example: one has laravel version 4.1.30 and 4.2.1, but the other one has version 4.1.27 and 4.2.0.

I tried to do composer install & update for laravel 4.1.* on 2 different computer. One give me version. 4.1.30, but the other give me 4.1.27.

Why is that there are two of it? What is the difference?

Comment: Good question.  I remember being a little confused by this too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first repository link in your question (`https://github.com/laravel/laravel`) is to build an application using `Laravel 4` and you should use this (`laravel/laravel`) repository if you want to build an application using the `Laravel` framework.

On the other hand, the second one which is `https://github.com/laravel/framework`; it's the core code of the Laravel framework and there is a note available in that `Github` page as given below:

> **Note:** This repository contains the core code of the Laravel framework.
>   If you want to build an application using Laravel 4, visit the main
>   [Laravel repository](https://github.com/laravel/laravel).

So, if you want to contribute in the `Laravel Framework` then clone this repository. This is the core code repository/`Laravel Framework (Kernel)` and it's `laravel/framework` not for building an application.

### Installation:

For installing the `Laravel` to build an application you may use:

```
// Via Composer Create-Project
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

Also you may use this (using `Laravel` installer and it's faster than `composer` install):

```
// Via Laravel Installer
laravel new projectname
```

For this, you need to download the `Laravel installer PHAR archive` first. For detail information, check [Via Laravel Installer](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#install-laravel) on `Laravel` website.

Answer (score 3):

The recommended method of installing Laravel is via Composer with the following command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

This uses the `laravel/laravel` repository as the beginning for your project. One of `laravel/laravel`'s Composer dependencies is `laravel/framework`, which'll get installed to your copy of `laravel/laravel`'s `vendor` directory along with any dependencies you add yourself.

Everything in `laravel/laravel` is part of your application code - you'd tweak it, check it into your version control, etc. The stuff in `laravel/framework` is stuff you use, but don't touch, and it's exempted from version control.

Answer (score 0):

One is the application you'd use as an end user, the other is the core packages which make up the framework.

So when you install laravel/laravel it pulls in the components from laravel/framework into the /vendor directory.